# Convert GeoDataFrame with one row to GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

I have a large geopandas GeoDataFrame which I want to convert to GeoJSON row by row and send off to an API. The API can only receive one entry at a time. I don't want to convert the dataframe all at once as it's taking too much memory. However, applying `to_json()` to a single row fails.

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

d = {'col1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [Point(1, 2), Point(2, 1)]}
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d)

gdf.to_json()        # works
gdf.loc[0].to_json() # fails
```

The single row is a pandas series which does not know about geometries.

```
type(gdf.loc[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

However, this also fails

```
gdf2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(gdf.loc[0])
type(gdf2)       # <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
gdf2.to_json()   # AttributeError: No geometry data set
gdf2.columns     # Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Apparently, it does not have a `geometry` column.

How can I convert a single row to GeoJSON?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, this works...

```
gdf.iloc[[0]].to_json()
```

Using a list will avoid dropping the row-column structure and the GeoDataFrame class apparently.

Comment: This isn’t specific to geopandas - you were dropping the row dimension which returns a pandas series. So geometry was in the index and the data is no longer a geoseries. Your approach is right on :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @michael. Coming from R I was familiar with the dimensions of an array unexpectedly changing... but never was aware of this this particular syntax with pandas.

Comment: ahh - yeah luckily they won't change unpredictably, but you do need to learn the rules. slicing with a constant reduces the dimensionality, slicing with a list/array/slicer preserves the dimensionality and just reduces the length along that dimension. concretely, `iloc[[0]]`, `iloc[[0, 1]]`, `iloc[:]`, and `iloc[:5]` reduce the length of the first dimension, wheras `iloc[0]` drops  the first dimension.